# Rails `has_secure_password` not working over API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm very confused. I've got a Rails app that I'm using as an API. I'm used the gem `rack-cors` to allow to cross domain AJAX. If I submit a new user details via console, the user is created fine. If I submit a new user via an Angular app (API) or using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) I get the error:

`{"success":false,"message":"Password can't be blank and Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters
)"}`

However If I render the params on my `User` controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  render json: { user: @user, params: params }
  return
  respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: { success: true, user: @user } }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: { success: false, message: @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I get the `password` and `password_confirmation` ok like as per screenshot attached:

[image]

I've pin-pointed the problem to `has_secure_password` method. If I remove it, the user is created fine, however I don't get password encryption and the whole lot. Its worth noting that I'm using Mongoid and have added `has_secure_password` like so:

```
class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Enum
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  ...
```

Its also important to notice that I'm using my own authentication rather than devise, etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you whitelisting the password and password_confirmation params in your `users_params` method? See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Also you have a `return` statement in the middle of your controller action. This means that the function will exit before the user is actually created. Since you also are calling render you will get a double render error as well. Please clean up the code and edit.

Comment: The `return` was only so I could show the properties of `params` and stopping the rest of the code in the controller to run. Basically for testing. And yes, I have whitelisted both `password` and `password_confirmation` in  `user_params`

Comment: Hmm, did you add a `field :password_digest` to your `User` model? This would probably raise an error unless you have set mongoid to allow a dynamic schema but it's the only thing I can think of at the moment. I haven't used `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` with mongoid but I'm pretty sure it does not declare the field for you as it is oblivious to the underlying ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have whitelisted the `password` and `password_confirmation` parameters.

Also you had both a render and return call in the middle of your controller action which will prevent it from working as intended.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: { success: true, user: @user } }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: { success: false, message: @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

private 

def user_params
  params.require(:user)
        .allow(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :accept)
end
```

On a side note - when a resource is created successfully you should return a [201 CREATED status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2) and set the `LOCATION` response header to the location of the newly created resource:

```
if @user.save
  format.json do 
    render json: { success: true, user: @user }, 
           status: :created, 
           location: user_url(@user)

  end
end
```

I usually use the [responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) for this as typing out the same boilerplate code for responding to different formats is pretty tedious.

Comment: As per previous comment, the `render json: { user: @user, params: params } return` was so just I could test it. I've removed it now and still get the same errors. Thanks for responders gem tip and the status though.